# Square negative number in go

Tags: go, math, exponent, math.sqrt

I'm having problems to square a negative number in go...

`(2*(1-0.5)-4)/((4*(4-2))/(2-1))^(1/2) = -1.06066017`

but with go I get `NaN`

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print(math.Sqrt((2*(1-0.5) - 4) / ((4 * (4 - 2)) / (2 - 1))))
}
```

or if I use `math.Abs` like this:

```
fmt.Print(math.Sqrt(math.Abs((2*(1-0.5) - 4) / ((4 * (4 - 2)) / (2 - 1)))))
```

I got back: `0.6123724356957` that is not correct, the correct result is: `-1.06066017`

is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
(2*(1-0.5)-4)/((4*(4-2))/(2-1))^(1/2)
```

is evaluated as `(2*(1-0.5)-4)` divided by `((4*(4-2))/(2-1))^(1/2)` in your calculator, which indeed yields `-1.06..`.

But you gave Go `(2*(1-0.5)-4)/((4*(4-2))/(2-1))`, which is a negative number, and told it to calculate the square root of that, which would be complex.

So try:

```
fmt.Print((2*(1-0.5) - 4) / math.Sqrt(((4 * (4 - 2)) / (2 - 1))))
```

Comment: feel free to accept the answer, so others see, that the problem is solved ;)